# linphone code compilation

Tags: voip, sip

I have problem compiling linphone code. I have taken git clone of **linphone-iphone** and when i am trying to open it in xcode i see all the frameworks and other code missing(in red color). I have installed all ports specified in README file of linphone but still all frameworks are missing.  I tried to google also but it was of no use.

>

I am very new to SIP/linphone and this issue is driving me crazy. Can anyone help me to solve this issue and show me directions to proceed further.

Thanks
Gurpreet

Comment: Just go through README file in linphone source directory. And follow steps.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the app to compile yesterday using the instructions inside the README file. I am not sure if those have been updated since you last got the code but now it works. The one trick was to make sure you don't checkout the code into a path which has a space in it. For example: /Users/NAME/Documents/Folder with Space/git/linphone-iphone would be bad.

Other than that, I made sure to build the linphone target and not the linphone-no-gpl-thirdparties but that's because I didn't mind gpl. Their website seems to be going a refactor at the moment so I have copied their readme here:

```
                            LINPHONE ON IPHONE
                ******************************************
```

BUILD PREQUISITES

---

Linphone for iPhone depends on liblinphone sdk. This SDK is generated from makefiles and shell scripts.
You must first install both xcode with iPhone OS SDK and MacPorts (www.macports.org) for these scripts to work.

Once xccode and macports are installed, open a terminal and install the required build-time tools with:

```
$ sudo port install nawk coreutils automake autoconf libtool intltool wget pkgconfig cmake yasm doxygen
```

Install gas-preprosessor.pl  (http://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor/ ) to be copied into /opt/local/bin :

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor/master/gas-preprocessor.pl
$ sudo mv gas-preprocessor.pl /opt/local/bin/.
$ sudo chmod +x /opt/local/bin/gas-preprocessor.pl
```

Link macport libtoolize to glibtoolize

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/glibtoolize /opt/local/bin/libtoolize
```

Link host's strings to simulator SDK

```
$ ln -s  /usr/bin/strings /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/strings
```

BUILDING THE SDK

---

- GPL third parties versus non GPL third parties

This sdk can be generated in 2 flavors. Firt is with GPL third parties, it means liblinphone includes GPL third parties like FFMPEG or x264. 
If you choose this flavor, your final application must comply with GPL in any case. This is the default mode.

To generate the liblinphone multi arch sdk in GPL mode, do:
    $ cd submodules/build
    $ make all

ALTERNATIVELY, you can force liblinphone to use only non GPL code except for liblinphone, mediastremer2, ortp, exosip, osip.
If you choose this flavor, your final application  is still subject to GPL except if you have a commercial license for liblinphone, mediastremer2, ortp, exosip, osip.

To generate the liblinphone multi arch sdkin non GPL mode, do:
    $ cd submodules/build
    $ make all enable_gpl_third_parties=no

The resulting sdk is in liblinphone-sdk/ directory.

In case you upgrade your IOS SDK, you may force rebuilding everything, by doing
    $ make veryclean
    $ make all

BUILDING THE APPLICATION

---

After the SDK is built, just open the linphone xcode project with Xcode, and press "Run".

- Note regarding third party components subject to license

The liblinphone-sdk is compiled with third parties code that are subject to patent license, specially: AMR, SILK and  X264 codecs.
Linphone controls the embedding of these codecs thanks to the preprocessor macros HAVE_SILK, HAVE_AMR, HAVE_X264 positioned in xcode project.
Before embeding these 3 codecs in the final application, make sure to have the right to do so.

LIMITATIONS, KNOWN BUGS

---

- Video capture does not work in simulator (not implemented by simulator ?).
- Sound does not work well (or at all) in simulator